# Make separate php arrays from one json file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this json source file:

```
{
  "results":
    [
      {
        "movie_title":"A Monster Calls",
        "cinema":"downtown"
      },
      {
        "movie_title":"A Monster Calls",
        "cinema":"uptown"
      },
      {
        "movie_title":"A Monster Calls",
        "cinema":"downtown"
      },
      {
        "movie_title":"A Monster Calls",
        "cinema":"downtown"
      }
    ]
}
```

and I am writing my array like this (simplified for clarity):

```
$json_data = json_decode($html, true);
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_data['results']); $i++) {

    $movieTitle = $json_data['results'][$i]["movie_title"];
    $cinema = $json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"];

    $moviesList[]= array(
      "movieTitle" => $movieTitle,
      "cinema" => $cinema
    );
}
```

But what I want to do is output 2 separate arrays. One is all films showing in "downtown" cinema, and the other array all films showing in "uptown". The order in the json file will change, so I have to do it by name.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi. First fix your JSON. It has some extra commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$downtownArray = array();
$uptownArray = array();

$json_data = json_decode($html, true);
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_data['results']); $i++) {

    $movieTitle = $json_data['results'][$i]["movie_title"];
    $cinema = $json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"];

    if ($cinema == 'uptown') {
        $uptownArray[]= array(
            "movieTitle" => $movieTitle,
            "cinema" => $cinema
        );  
    } else {
        $downtownArray[]= array(
            "movieTitle" => $movieTitle,
            "cinema" => $cinema
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($json_data['results'] as $result) {
  $cinema = $result['cinema'];
  $moviesList[$cinema] []= [
    "movieTitle" => $result['movie_title'],
    // ...
  ];
}
```

The code classifies the results by the `cinema` field and stores them into `$moviesList` array. So, for example, the `uptown` results will be stored into `$moviesList['uptown']`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
    $json_data = json_decode($html, true);
$moviesDwn=array();
 $moviesUp=array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($json_data['results']); $i++) {

        $movieTitle = $json_data['results'][$i]["movie_title"];
        $cinema = $json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"];
       if ($json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"]='uptown')
        $moviesUp[]= array(
          "movieTitle" => $movieTitle,
          "cinema" => $cinema
        );
    else if  ($json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"]='updown')
        $moviesDwn[]= array(
          "movieTitle" => $movieTitle,
          "cinema" => $cinema
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please , **FIX**you JSON ,as it has some extra comma and then try with below codes

> If you want to just separate the two array than use **foreach(){};**

```
     foreach ($json_data['results'] as $result) {
        $DownTown_List[$result['cinema']] []= $result['movie_title'];
     }
```

*OR*

> if you want to do other operation with the Indexes then use **for(){};**

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($json_data['results']); $i++) {

        if($json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"] === "downtown"){
            $DownTown_List["downtown"][] = $json_data['results'][$i]["movie_title"];
        }
        if($json_data['results'][$i]["cinema"] === "uptown"){
           $DownTown_List["uptown"][] = $json_data['results'][$i]["movie_title"];
       }
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($DownTown_List);exit;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [downtown] => Array
        (
            [0] => A Monster Calls
            [1] => A Monster Calls
            [2] => A Monster Calls
        )

    [uptown] => Array
        (
            [0] => A Monster Calls
        )

)
```